# Undertanding rank-deficiencies of the differential of matrix function $f(A)=A^3$ in the space of $3 \times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-rank

This a follow-on of this [question "Q"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644191/305862) asked some days ago on Maths SE to which I had given an answer that will be denoted "A".

This question "Q" was dealing with the mapping :

$$f_{A_0}(X)=A_0^2X+A_0XA_0+XA_0^2$$

In fact (it wasn't mentionned in "Q"), this mapping is, in the 9-dimensional space $\frak{M}_{3 \times 3}$ of $3 \times 3$ matrices, the differential of function $f:A \to A^3$ in "point" $A_0$.

As such $f_{A_0}$ is a linear function having a certain rank $r(f_{A_0})$ which can be maximal, i.e., equal to $9$ (for most $A_0$) or have a rank deficiency (equivalent naming : "rank drop"), like $8$ for some $A_0$ or even less in very rare cases (see statistical study below).

It will be easier to work on the complementary value of the rank, i.e., the dimension of the kernel :

$$\underbrace{\dim(\ker(f_{A_0}))}_k = 9 - \underbrace{\operatorname{rank}(f_{A_0})}_r$$

Taking a pragmatic approach, I have done a large scale simulation on matrices $A$ having *integer entries* between $-3$ and $3$ which has given these *approximate* proportion of values for the dimension $k$ of the kernel of $f_{A_0}$ :

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6 \\\hline &97 \% &2.6 \%&0.2\%&0.1 \%&0.0 \%&0.0 \%&0.1 \%\end{array}$$

Side remark : In fact the relative percentages aren't important ; the important fact is the "holes" in the spectrum  : no matrices for $k=4,5,7,8$. I know that this approach doesn't meet the approval of some readers : this question has been downvoted probably for this reason, but I don't bother, I think that all the tools we now have, in particular simulation methods, are good to use in order to establish **conjectures**.

**Question 1** : Set apart the fact that in a large majority of cases this differential is injective, how is it possible to explain the presence of these particular cases ($k=1, 2,3,6$) and the absence of other cases ?

Let us enter into the details.

- **Case $k=1$** : for matrices  $A$ having a one-dimensional kernel, I observe on my simulations that this kernel is **always** with rank-1 matrices $X$. Why ? Moreover, one doesn't see the rationale existing between $A$ and $X$ (btw, it was the main question in question "Q").

Two examples of a matrix $A$ and an element $X$ of the kernel of $f_A$ :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&1\\1&-2&2\\-1&2&2\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\2&1&0\\0&-2&0\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } X=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\4&-2&3\end{pmatrix}$$

Let us turn now to other cases $k=2,3,6$ where $X$ has (necessarily) rank $1$ :

- **Case k=2** : examples

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } X_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, X_2=\begin{pmatrix}-2&2&0\\0&1&2\\-4&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

- **Case k=3** : example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&0\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We are here in a particular case of a matrix where rank$(A)=2$, rank$(A^2)=1$ and $A^3=A^2$.

- **Case k=6** : example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&-2\\2&0&1\\2&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix has a very specific property $A^3=3I$. In fact, all matrices of this category ($k=6$) are such that $A^3=\mu A$ for a certain real number $A$. Why that ?
(Another example of this special case $k=6$ can be seen in my former answer "A").

**Question 2** (the main question in fact) How can the disparate observations seen above be understood and proved under a common globalizing explanation ?

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313769/305862.

Comment: Is it known what happens for $X \mapsto AX + XA$?

Comment: @ronno You are right that I could have had a look at the differential of $A \to A^2$. I thought that $AX+XA=B$ or $AX+XA=0$, being [Sylvester equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), have well known solutions.

Comment: @ronno I realize that I could also have studied the differential of $A \to A^3$ for $2 \times 2$ matrices...